# SwiftData @Query: 'Query' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, swift-data

I'm trying out SwiftData and came across the following error when trying to use `@Query`:

`'Query' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context`

```
import FirebaseFirestore
import SwiftData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var context
    @Query var models: [DataModel]                // <-- ERROR HERE

    var body: some View { ... }
}
```

What is this error and why is it happening?

Answer (score 1):

This error can come up in the common situation of having both some of Firebase's libraries and `SwiftData` imported in the same file. I guess they each have `@Query` in their libraries.

You can fix this error by calling `@SwiftData.Query(...)` in order to specify that you want to work with `SwiftData`'s version, or vice versa for the Firebase version.